# Architecture for a Decentralized Distributed Application

Tags: architecture, distributed-computing

we are maintaining a planning application which is deployed on several physically seperated sites. The sites use a multi-master replication (using Oracle 10g DB) which mean there is no central site (decentralized system).
However as the number of sites grows - so do our woes: more conflicts which should be manually resolved.

We are going to re-implement the application, and would like to consider alternatives to this architecture.

The data that is shared between the sites is of 2 flavors:

- Maps (Append-only data, stored as files. Metadata stored in DB)
- Plans and related data (stored as relational data in the DB)

All of the data needs to be present in all sites, however it is not critical for it to be available instantly.

Sites should be able to work even when disconnected from the network.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to expand on "so do our woes", so that the rest of us can provide answers of any value.

Answer (score 3):

The best architectures are ones that fit appropriately into the context of the problem: what are the drivers that ultimately shape what the best architecture and solution look like?

For example (picking up on Yuriys point): your woes could be performance and/or data management related - both require addressing but it's unlikely you'll get one solution that addresses both, they might even be contradictory.

In terms of data management I would suggest you need to have a master copy of the data which is "truth".  But that might not bee so good for performance - of course it depends on the approach.

In terms of specifics: I'd start with the data: model it, make sure you understand it, understand the current data flows and how they relate to business process. You want to get to the point where you can say "this we do because the business process legitimately requires it" and "we do this because of a technical limitation we should not have".

In a general sense you need to:

1. Take the **context** of your problem as input.
2. This will help shape your **scoring criteria** (this is how you will rate the ideas you come up with).
3. Define **initial high level solution options** / directions.  These are blue-sky discussions that can be relatively free of constraints: think big, think outside the box.  The critical point is to not start thinking in terms of implementation - or even specific technologies.  You can also put business constraints to the side: "well we do this because the current business process is X, if we did Y (using a this new technology) we could then do Z and reduce operational costs".
4. **Review and score** these against your scoring criteria.
5. Pursue **logical options**: basically take output of 3 & 4 and take them to the next level.  You may want to start thinking about enterprise / design patterns at this point.
6. **Review and score** these against your scoring criteria
7. Pursue **implementation options**: you need a component to do "X": do you re-use, buy or build?  Are there best of breed tools you can use?  Are they compatible with your current infrastructure?  And so on.
8. **Review and score** these against your scoring criteria.
9. Record outcome (**the reasons why**) in an Architectural Decisions Register for future reference; this should / must include the inputs and outputs of the previous steps.  The idea here is to prevent people who come after you from having to do all that work again - or blindly overwriting your well thought-through decision with a poor one.

**Update: Specifics**

- You're using "Multi-Master" replication - what about Master-Slave?
- You're using database replication - what about a solution that isn't database centric?
- Have a look for design patterns specific to data and/or distributed systems; [Data Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648420.aspx) looks like a good start (I haven't read it myself, and maybe Oracle offer similar material that might be more suited to the specifics of your platform).
- If sites are off-line can you lock certain tables / data so that they can't be changed until online again?
- Use a "check-out" source control approach to ensure that data changes are well controlled.
- Take a look at different caching approaches, that might give you some useful ideas as the basic concept is to keep locals copies of data for quick access - without letting them get out-of-date.
- Have a look at Multi-tenant Architectures, they often have to deal with segregating data in different ways and working across distributed environments.

Yes I did provide a general answer - but the information given was also fairly general :)

Comment: Thanks Adrian. This is a through architectural formation and analysis process, and I gave you +1 for that. However it is a general answer, and does not direct my specific problem. I am not looking for ways to come with an architecture and rate one. I need architectural ideas for my specific problem. I'd be happy to give more details on my problem.